# htaccess conditionals

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd, setenv, conditional-statements

I have setup htpasswd authentication on my live site and it works great, but I don't want to be asked for a password when I am working on the development environment.

In my httpd.conf file I have:

```
SetEnv APP_ENV "development"
```

In my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

I was wondering if there was anyway of putting a conditional around the htppasswd stuff so that when `APP_ENV` is `development` that I  don't get prompted for a password.

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are able to, you should think about upgrading to [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/new_features_2_4.html) (or the latest 2.3 beta build since 2.4 isn't quite released yet).

One of the new features available are [Authorization Containers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic) - making it much simpler to define access requirements using the [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive.

You should end up with something like:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /path/to/file/groups

SetEnv APP_ENV "development"

<RequireAll>
  <RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
      #main requirements
      Require group user
      #other conditions if needed for non-dev/non-local
    </RequireAll>

    <RequireAll>
      #allow direct if development
      Require env APP_ENV development
    </RequireAll>

    <RequireAll>
      <RequireAny>
        #allow loopback and local network
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
        Require ip 10.2
      </RequireAny>
    </RequireAll>
  <RequireAny>

  #other conditions if needed for everyone

  <RequireNone>
    #blacklist
  </RequireNone>
</RequireAll>
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the way of building if conditional blocks with env variables is using **mod_macro** module.
I made an example previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343621/conditions-in-apache/6346407#6346407).

In this particular case you would have on top of the VirtualHost file (before the VirtualHost definition):

```
<Macro ConditionalBlockMacroSecurity_production>
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    require valid-user
</Macro>
<Macro ConditionalBlockMacroSecurity_development >
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
       Header set MyHeader "Hello this is DEVELOPMENT envirronment. It took %D microseconds for Apache to serve this request."
    </IfModule>
</Macro>
```

And inside the Virtualhost:

```
Use ConditionalBlockMacroSecurity_${APP_ENV}
```

where path to the htpassword file could also be set as a parameter of the macro.

The downside of this solution is that you need to install mod_macro on the production server, it's not a commonly installed module and you will need some control of the production env to do that. On the other side, a simple solution is to have several version of your virtualhosts depending on the environment, and to add some comments on the Auth section. But if you are searching for a generic solution it certainly means it's a recurent problem and you want to avoid manual editing of files, in such cases mod_macro can become a very professional way of capitalizing your apache experiences, until your apache configurations becomes a single macro with parameters, calling a lot of other macros.

Answer (score 2):

Conditionals in Apache config work only once, when the configuration is [re]loaded.

What I would do is create a second VirtualHost with the same root directory, and control access using Deny/Allow based on IP address there.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
Require valid-user
Allow from <dev IP>
Satisfy Any
```

This will require that `Require valid-user` *or* `Allow from <dev IP>` applies.

Comment: That would work, but I have to use `Satisfy All` because of other constraints.

Comment: @gpojd would it be possible for you to post your entire setup?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to post it. My .htaccess is the similar as the OP's, but I also restrict by IP address and have `Satisfy All`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.htaccess` file you can nest the blocks within the IfDefine directive, like:

```
<IfDefine PROD>
  bla bla bla
</IfDefine>
```

Then make sure to pass `-D PROD` as argument when you start apache. This section would only run if PROD is defined. In Ubuntu you can do this by, for example, editing `/etc/apache2/envvars` and adding this line at the end:

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS="-D PROD"
```

You can "inverse" it by perhaps using something like `<IfDefine !DEV>` to only run when its not the development environment, and then pass -D DEV in that environment, and leave the production sites as is without having to edit envvars.

Modify accordingly to suit your needs!